# name error first_name is not defined, after I defined it

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that returns a fully formmated full name, here is the code,

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    full_name = (first_name + ' ' + last_name)
    return full_name.title()
    _musician = get_formatted_name('jimi', 'hendrix')
    print(musician)
get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name)
```

I keep getting an error in the shell, NameError: name 'first_name' is not defined.

Comment: No, you clearly **did not define it**. `full_name = (first_name + ' ' + last_name)` is a local variable inside `get_formatted_name`, however, when you call `get_formatted` in the global scope, **what were you expecting `first_name` and `last_name` to refer to??? What do you expect to return? Note, all the code in your function after `return full_name.title()` is unreachable... is this an indentation issue?

Comment: Where did you define it? Are you talking about the function parameter?

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `first_name` anywhere. You have tried to use it without defining it anywhere first.

To get the code above to work you need to get rid of the last line, de-indent the final 2, rename `_musician` to `musician` and it will work, as below:

```py
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    full_name = (first_name + ' ' + last_name)
    return full_name.title()

musician = get_formatted_name('jimi', 'hendrix')
print(musician)
```